# PHP edit if file isset don't change

Tags: php, image, edit, isset

This is my edit page update script. I have a problem. On each update, script updates image name and inserts into MySQL. I would like that system doesn't inserts or updates file name if it is NULL (isset). Here is my code about that:

```
    <?php
require 'aed-config.php';
require 'class.upload.php';


function gen_random_string($length=16)
{
    $chars ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";//length:36
    $final_rand='';
    for($i=0;$i<$length; $i++)
    {
        $final_rand .= $chars[ rand(0,strlen($chars)-1)];

    }
    return $final_rand;
}
$pic_name = gen_random_string();

$image = new Upload( $_FILES[ 'image' ] );
    if ( $image->uploaded ) {

        $image->file_new_name_body = $pic_name;
        $image->image_convert = 'jpg';
        $image->image_resize = true;
        $image->image_ratio_crop = true;
        $image->image_x = 460;
        $image->image_y = 300;
        $image->Process( '../img' );

        $image->allowed = array ( 'image/*' );
    }


$pic = $pic_name.'.jpg';
$title = $_POST['title'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$id = $_POST['memids'];

$sql = "UPDATE about_us 
        SET title=?, content=?, pic=?
        WHERE id=?";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title,$content,$pic,$id));
header("location: about.php");

?>
```

Comment: just check if `$_FILES['image']` is set then update the pic else reassign the old value or don't update it in update query..

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like using an simple if condition

```
if($pic_name != null AND isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $q->execute(array($title,$content,$pic,$id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First dont generate a filename and create an Upload object if you dont need it.

```
if ($_FILES['image'])
{
    // Generate filename and create your Upload object as well as the $pic variable
}
```

And then the query section..

```
$executeArray = array($title, $content);
$sql = "UPDATE about_us
        SET title = ?, content = ?, ";

if (isset($pic)
{
    $executeArray[] = $pic;
    $sql .= "pic = ?, ";
}

$sql .= "WHERE id = ?";
$executeArray[] = $id;

$q->execute($executeArray);
```